# Is there any way to understand if the card(emv or magnetic) is used first time at ATM or POS? For EMV card ATC is reliable?

Tags: emv, magnetic-cards

Is there any way to understand if the card(emv or magnetic) is used first time at ATM or POS? 
For EMV card ATC is reliable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **"first time"** could be different.

You can ask for **ATC** after selection ( command `80CA9F5200` ) and if it equals **0000**, Get Processing Options wasn't performed, what means there wasn't any transaction.
Bit if if > 0000, it does not mean what "full" transaction was on card. ATC shows number of launch command Get Processing Options.

For **Visa** card you can find specific bit in CVR ( CVR3, BIT5 ) "New card". He shows if successful online transaction was performed with card.

Comment: It means if  ATC Returned 0000 then we can say card is new but if ATC > 0000 it may or may not the new card. Am I right? How we can identify for MASTER AND DISCOVER CARD. Any Idea??

Comment: Еxactly. For Mchip and Discover I don't know how to properly check this.

Answer (score 1):

You can trust ATC for EMV transaction but there is no counter for magnetic transaction.
 There is one bit( new card bit) that was set in first EMV transaction. If the Last Online ATC Register is 0 then “New card” bit in the TVR will be set to 1. You could check that bit to see if this transaction is first for this card.

Comment: But if i am right. their lengths are different for visa and master (i am talking about 9F10) Can you help me to parse 9F10 tags; 9F10 02 10 80 00 10 2C 02 00 01 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF (Master Card)
9F10 06 01 0A 03 80 20 00 (Visa)

Comment: You are't right about IAD (byte 2 bit 5). "New card" you could fild only on Visa card CVR3, BIT5. 9F10 (DKI 1b)  (CVN 1b)  (CVR 6b) and hereinafter different data for Visa/Mchip.

Comment: @tmc , yes there are different 9F10 tags for different applications but I do not have a list. Generally for mastercard, skip first 3 bytes of 9F10 to access IAD.

Comment: 9F10  - tag
06  - length
01 -  can be wither derivative key index or cryptogram version number.  
0A03802000 -  card holder verification results

-- Check how you are personalizing your card

Answer (score 0):

I found ATC is incremented just after GPO is performed. It is possible that transaction falied just after GPO,

Next time when we fire GPO, we get the value > 0 ( ATC already incremented) here we can't say that card is not new because yet to processed first transaction successfully.

so I think ATC value is not a parameter to find out whether card is new or already used. [Sometime as per setting we need to check the card is new or not to perform certain activity]

Answer (score 0):

There are two `ATC`-related values could be read using `GET_DATA`: the current `ATC` and `Last Online ATC`. For a new card that never went online the `Last Online ATC` would be zero. This should be true for a 'classical' scheme of the EMV technology employment by a traditional payment system.

Hope this helps

Comment: Despite the fact that the tag is defined in the EMV not all cards support Last Online ATC in GET_DATA. For example it is absent in Mchip.

Comment: Then there are no 100% proof way to confirm that a card had never interacted with the issuer after personalisation